# How to open a local file in Office on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ms-office

I've saved a file locally and want to open it in Word if installed. For example my file's URL is:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{guid}/Library/Caches/MyFile.docx
```

My Office URL is:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{guid}/Library/Caches/MyFile.docx|p|my-protocol
```

When Word launches it says:

> The link you clicked on is invalid and the document cannot be opened

However if I feed the original URL to a `UIDocumentInteractionController` it opens correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the URL to Word directly you are attempting to violate your Application Sandbox - Word doesn't have access to your App's directory, so it can't read the file.

You have to use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` to prompt the user to open the document in Word or you need to store the document somewhere that Word can read it (this would be external to your device - on a cloud store somewhere)

Comment: This would send a copy over to Office right? What about in-place editing where changes would be sent back to your app? I have implemented a File Provider extension that would allow in-place editing when using the Files app. How could I achieve something like this directly from my app?